# BatchScanner with limits per range

Tags: accumulo

Is there a way to get first n whole rows using BatchScanner for each range.

I would like to pull latest user activity for multiple users up to say 100 whole rows per user. Row key starts with user id followed with timestamp.

Thanks,

Dejan

Answer (score 1):

Dejan -- Take a look at the [WholeRowIterator](https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators/user/WholeRowIterator.java). Here's some example code for how you would use it.

```
Connector conn = getConnector();
BatchScanner bs = conn.createBatchScanner("mytable", new Authorizations(), 4);
IteratorSetting iterator = new IteratorSetting(100, WholeRowIterator.class);
bs.addScanIterator(iterator);

for (Entry<Key,Value> entry : bs) {
  SortedMap<Key,Value> row = WholeRowIterator.decodeRow(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: That's pretty close, but if you want the first N rows, you might want the Scanner instead: Scanner bs = conn.createScanner("mytable", new Authorizations()); you can also use bs.setBatchSize(N) if you know you only want N rows.

Comment: Ahh, good point! I wasn't thinking about the problems using a BatchScanner might create. A Scanner instead of a BatchScanner will definitively give you the 100 most recent records (in some table where the most recent rows sort first)

Comment: For performance reasons I would like to use BatchScanner. I need to get first 100 results for multiple users. With Scanner data is collected one user at the time. Of course I can make several threads to collect data using Scanner. I was hoping to avoid additional complexity using BatchScanner.